# Using substring to calculate Date of birth

Tags: java

My assignment is to write and run a program that does the following:

- Print a message inviting the user to enter his name and birthday (dd/mm/yyyy).
- Prompt the user to enter todays date
- Calculate the user's age (always assume 30 days)
- Display a message informing the user about his age, like "Dear Michael, you are 12 years, 4 months and 2 days old."

My question is, how do I put in the month, day and the year of the user and the current date, month and year, and then calculate the users age? Our teacher allowed to use substrings, but I'm not sure on how to start? Any tips?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment3 {
    static Scanner scan = new
    Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        String name=scan.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth");

        int dateofbirth=scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter today's date");

        int currentdate=scan.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: `int dateofbirth=scan.nextInt();` will not work if you're expecting dd/mm/yyyy.  Have you looked at the Javadocs for String.substring()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) which contains 3 ints for year month and day ( see link for detailed information)

there you got the function .getDay .getMonth and .getYear with which you can compare and calculate your current age ;)

Comment: that would be an easy way without substrings

Answer (score 0):

The `substring(int beginIndex)` method "cut" a string at the given index, and return the remaining part of the string.

The `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)` method also cut the String at given indexes, but return the String between these two indexes.

Here's an example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcdefg";

    System.out.println(str.substring(2));
    // print : "cdefg"
    System.out.println(str.substring(2,4));
    // print : "cde"
}
```

Now, in your case, the user will input its birthdate in this format : `dd/mm/yyyy`, so you know where to parse the inputed string to get in different variable the day, the month and the year of birth of the user.

Good luck with that !

For more informations about the String class and its method, see : [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get the dates as `String` via `scanner.next()`. `nextInt` leads to an exception if input is e. g. `"15/03/2017"`.
One possibility is to use `java.util.Calendar`:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name");
    String name = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter your date of birth");
    String dateofbirth = scan.next();

    System.out.println("Please enter today's date");
    String currentdate = scan.next();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar birthdayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    birthdayCal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(dateofbirth));
    Calendar todayCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    todayCal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(currentdate));
    long years = todayCal.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birthdayCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    long months = todayCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) - birthdayCal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    long days = todayCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - birthdayCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Dear {0}, you are {1} years, {2} months and {3} days old", name, years, months, days));
}
```

With Java 8 you may use API from `java.time.*`. Note that `SimpleDateFormat#parse` may throw a `ParseException`.

Comment: I haven't got enough repu to comment Dr3xler's answer: this is also possible but these methods are deprecated as well as the constructor. So I would not use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method:String[] split(String regex);
it splits string by regex.

for example,`"dd/mm/yyyy".split("/");`it will return `{"dd","mm","yyyy"}`.
you can get birth and date by this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] str = new String[3];
    String s = scan.next();
    str = s.split("/");
}
```

but you should change string into int when you want to caculate them.